# Decider that reject All inputs if and only if Goldbach's conjecture has a counter example

Tags: number-theory, computability, turing-machines, goldbachs-conjecture

I want to design a $Decider$ such that for every input accept if and only if Goldbach's conjecture is true and reject all inputs if and only if Goldbach's conjecture has a counter example.

I made a $Decider$ that accept all string if and only if Goldbach's conjecture was right by assuming that Goldbach's conjecture has a $TM_{goldbach}$ simply i check if $w$ is represented a even number or odd number if it represent a odd number i change that to a even by adding a dummy Char for instance and then i pass it to $TM_{goldbach}$ which compute 2 prime number that summation of those make the input length (or the number that input is represented) If $TM_{goldbach}$ halt the $Decider$ accept (Means that $TM_{goldbach}$ find the the equivalent prime numbers).

But this definition accept lots of input even when we have a counter example i know there should be trick that i can reject every string when  Goldbach's conjecture was wrong (finding counter example? how?).

Thanks for help.

===edit===

Apparently making such Decider which I've described above leads us to contradiction.

Thanks.

Comment: TMs don't accept or reject input, they produce output from input (or sometimes fail to halt)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Thanks , I edit my question and change TM to a Decider